# IDApython confused with get_32bit(ea) function behavior

Tags: idapython

I am using some code like this

```
   import idaapi
   print(idaapi.get_32bit(0x0055f4a0))
```

it must return 32 bit of address as int

but it returns 1408011093
is it wrong conversion?
its length is less than the maximum length of int

but it somehow changes the value 
I expected to get return value like ‭5633184‬

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_32bit(0x0055f4a0)` returns the 32-bit value in your IDB at the address `0x0055f4a0`. 1408011093 decimal is `0x53EC8B55` in hex which fits in 32 bits. In little endian format this corresponds to the byte sequence `55 8B EC 53`, so 0x0055f4a0 is likely a function start.

To convert hex to decimal you don't need IDA APIs but just standard Python functionality, e.g. `str(int(0x0055f4a0))`. But this is best discussed on Stack Overflow since that's a programming question and not RE.

Comment: ty so  just need to go through the standard conversion